# How to do self join

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to do self-join I have written a code as well but its throwing an error and it seems that there is some issue with an alias.

Apart from this it would also be helpful for me if someone let me know any best site where I can learn query in MS Access. I searched a number of places everywhere, it is showing through UI Interface but I want to learn query in MS Access.

```
(SELECT distinct  itemname,vendorname,price,count(*)
from vendor_Details1
group by itemname,vendorname,price
order by vendorname) A
inner join
(SELECT distinct  itemname,vendorname,price,count(*)
from vendor_Details1
group by itemname,vendorname,price
order by vendorname) B
on A.vendorname=B.vendorname
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `vendor_Details1` is a table containing all sellings? And you want to know how often a vendor sold a product for a particular price? And why the required self-join? I consider MS Access about the worst RDBMS for learning SQL, because its SQL dialect diverges so very much from standard SQL.

Comment: Dear Thorsten i am not trying to learn SQl here its just i have some data in excel and i am trying to do that in access since i am not that good in excel. I hav eto find the list where vendor sold the same item but with different price in the same month.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.  However, "join" is an operator in the `FROM` clause that operates on two tables, views, or subqueries.

The structure of a self-join looks like:

```
select . . .              -- list of columns here
from t as t1 inner join   -- you need aliases for the table so you can distinguish the references
     t as t2
     on t1.? = t2.?       -- the join condition goes here
```

Your query doesn't even have a `select`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i ddn't get you actually i am trying to find the list of those vendors who sold the same item but with different price within the same month so for that i tried to do self join however i am getting an error could you please make changes in my code so that i can understand better.

Comment: @Aamir . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want.